# Show that two consistent systems are equivalent to each other

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics

> $A: n \times n$, $B: n \times m$ and $A$ is
>   invertible.
>
> Show that "$\forall \vec{b} \in \mathbb{R}^n, B \vec{x} = \vec{b}$ is
>   consistent" is equivalent to "$\forall \vec{b} \in \mathbb{R}^n, (AB)
>  \vec{x} = \vec{b}$ is consistent."

I know that $(AB)\vec{x}=\vec{b}$ can be written as $B\vec{x}=A^{-1}\vec{b}$ since we know that $A$ is invertible. The form $B\vec{x}=A^{-1}\vec{b}$ then allows us to equate the first and second expressions so that $\vec{b} = A^{-1}\vec{b}$. This means that $A^{-1} = I_n$ so that $A = I_n$ as well (since $A^{-1}(AB)\vec{x}=A^{-1}\vec{b} \Rightarrow B\vec{x} = A^{-1}\vec{b}$, and $BI_n = B$). So the expression $B\vec{x}=\vec{b} \equiv (AB)\vec{x}=\vec{b}$.

Can someone help me check my work or tell me where I've gone wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You make (at least) two errors. One is to assume that ($\forall \vec b$ ($AB\vec x=\vec b$ is constistent))$\iff$($\forall \vec b$ ($B\vec x=\vec b$ is constistent)) means that the two systems have the same solution, which is what you are implicitly doing by using the solution $\vec x$ to one system as purported solution to the other ("equate the first and second expressions"). That is not what it means that both systems are consistent under the same conditions. Another error is to deduce from $\vec{b} = A^{-1}\vec{b}$ that $A^{-1}=I$; that's just wrong.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid confusion, state the theorem
$$
\forall\vec{b}\in\mathbb{R}^{n}:\, B\vec{x}=\vec{b}
$$

is consistent is equivalent to 
$$
\forall\vec{v}\in\mathbb{R}^{n}:\,(AB)\vec{y}=\vec{b}
$$

No to see where things went wrong and what the confusion was:

Given $\vec{b}\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$ you looked at 
$$
(AB)\vec{x}=\vec{b}
$$

and wrote it as 
$$
B\vec{x}=A^{-1}\vec{b}
$$

so far so good.

Now you looked at the first part of the statement and said that $B\vec{x}=\vec{b}$
which is wrong.

The first part of the statement is that for every vector $\vec{b}$
the system of equations $B\vec{x}=\vec{b}$ is consistent but here
$\vec{x}$ is already a solution vector to 
$$
(AB)\vec{x}=\vec{b}
$$
 and not free variables we can assign any value to.

Consider this using an example, let $A=B=I$ and $\vec{b}=e_{1}$
$$
A\vec{x}=\vec{b}
$$

is indeed consistent and a solution is $\vec{x}=e_{1}$. but also
$$
(AB)\vec{x}=e_{2}
$$

is consistent, with a solution $\vec{x}=e_{2}$. So the problem was
to equate 
$$
A\vec{x}=(AB)\vec{x}
$$

Comment: What does $A\vec{x}=(AB)\vec{x}$ tell us? Can we invert $A$ on both sides and get $\vec{x} = B\vec{x}$?

Comment: @JoelB - it does tell you that, but you can't deduce this equality to start with

Comment: So how do we show that two consistent systems are equivalent then?

Comment: Will it work if we say that $B\vec{x} = \vec{b}$ is consistent is the same as $B\vec{x} = A^{-1}\vec{b}$ is consistent because $\forall \vec{b}$ in the first statement includes linear combinations of the form $A^{-1}\vec{b}$, and $\forall \vec{b}$ in the second statment includes any and all $\vec{b}$ in the first equation?